# how to get the SUM of certain rows based on an ID and populate column with the value without using a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to do this but I don't know how to do it without a loop.

Basically, for each `CustomerID + PaymentID`, I want to populate the column `"SumOfAmount"` with the total. The total will repeat for each row of that `CustomerID + PaymentID`.

[image]

How would I go about doing this without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [windowing function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT ID, CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, DeductionBucketID, Qty, Amount, Deductions
, SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, PaymentID) AS SumofAmount
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use the OVER keyword with the SUM aggregate to partition your data by the customer ID and payment ID. This code provides an example:

```
DECLARE @CustPaymentDetail AS TABLE
(
    CustomerID int,
    PaymentID int,
    ItemID int,
    Amount numeric(19,2)
);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62228, 1, 780);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62228, 1, 95.04);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62228, 1, 1443);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62228, 1, 136.43);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62228, 1, 12.99);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62238, 1, 130);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62238, 1, 702);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62238, 1, 19.49);
INSERT INTO @CustPaymentDetail (CustomerID, PaymentID, ItemID, Amount) VALUES (143, 62238, 1, 12.99);

SELECT
    *,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, PaymentID) AS SumOfAmount
FROM        @CustPaymentDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need updated statement with window function. Just replace MyTable with your table name

```
WITH    SomeData
          AS (
               SELECT CustomerID as NCustomerID
                   ,PaymentID AS NPaymentID
                   ,SUM(Amount) OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerID, PaymentID ) AS NSumOfAmount
                FROM MyTable
             )
    UPDATE MyTable
        SET SumOfAmount = n.NSumOfAmount
        FROM SomeData AS n
        WHERE customerId = n.NCustomerID
            AND PaymentID = n.NPaymentID

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```